# The method getText() is undefined for the type EditText -- How?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, gettext

Yes, I'm totally new to this platform, but getText() IS a method of EditText, is it not?

I just copied and pasted the exact error from my simple app, which I copied word-for-word from a web tutorial.  I believe it's self-explanatory.  It's an error that might only come up if there was a misspelling.  Below is the context.  Error is on the 3rd line down.

```
public void sendMessage (View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Would there be ANY circumstance where getText() would NOT be considered a method of EditText?

Comment: Try cleaning your project. (Go to **Project** -> **Clean...**)

Comment: That is weird. Funny, I saw something like this before and it turned out the guy had defined a class with the same name as the object he was tying to use from a library. Unlikely to be the issue here I know but thought I'd mention it. Strange that the compiler knows about the type EditText but not its getText() method.

Comment: @Ruairi I was just writing this as an answer. :)

Comment: Thanks Sam...I wish that was it.  I tried that, closed and opened Eclipse a couple of times, no change.  I'll look into Ruairi's suggestion now.

Comment: Double check your imports, do you have `import android.widget.EditText;`?

Comment: Didn't have that.  Added that.  Same error.  Also, didn't see any other occurrences of EditText except as... public class MainActivity<EditText> extends Activity { blah blah -- which Eclipse seemed have generate for me.

Comment: Great website and great denizens here. I'll try not to abuse it by being too much of a n00b in the future.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would there be ANY circumstance where getText() would NOT be considered a method of EditText?

No, `getText()` is a method in every version of `android.widget.EditText`. Unless you have created another class with the name `EditText`, this error is probably Eclipse being confused. Simply clean your project by going to **Project** -> **Clean...**

---

**Addition**
By subtyping MainActivity with EditText, you are inadvertently creating a new, local class named EditText which obscures Android's EditText class... In general, Activities do not need subtypes. So change this line:

```
public class MainActivity<EditText> extends Activity {
```

To:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

Comment: While the problem still exists, I truly believe that this answer is 100% correct and accurate, and that I need to go back to square one and redo it (it's a very small app) carefully.

Comment: The advice to clean your Eclipse is useful advice, though.  I have seen Eclipse get confused, and just cleaning it un-confused Eclipse.

Comment: BINGO!  Yep, that MainActivity<EditText>, which oddly enough was generated by Eclipse without my help, was the culprit!  Thanks!